# Make lstlisting honour baselinestretch

Tags: listings, line-spacing

I have to use `lstlisting` instead of `Verbatim` in a particular case, because math escape doesn't work properly with the latter. I managed to have both look the same, but `lstlisting` ignores my `baselinestretch` settings, so the line spacing is too big:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=0.94}
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={type}%
}
\lstset{
  language=scala,%
% baselinestretch=0.94,% keyword doesn't exist
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,%
  fancyvrb=true,%
  mathescape=true,%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
type Vertex = ($\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
Next Line
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{Verbatim}
type Vertex = ($\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
Next Line
Next Line
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

You can see the different line spacing here:

[image]

The difference is not that big, but it makes a huge impact on long listings. What is the best way to apply the base line stretching to `lstlisting`?

Comment: `basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily`

Comment: @egreg Great, that does it, although I found I have to use a value of `0.92` to have visually the same spacing.

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: You are right, that was I think a screen rendering glitch. I have a full A4 page now, and it seems it's indeed the same factor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily`

As the following example shows, the lines are spaced exactly in the same way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[scaled=.73]{beramono}
\fvset{baselinestretch=.94}
\lstdefinelanguage{scala}{
  morekeywords={type}
}
\lstset{
  language=scala,
  basicstyle=\linespread{.94}\ttfamily,
  fancyvrb=true,
  mathescape=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
type Vertex = ($\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
Next Line
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}

\kern-50pt % back up to see that the lines are equally spaced

\begin{Verbatim}
type Vertex = ($\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{pre}$: Label, $\mathit{lb}_\mathsf{post}$: Label)
Next Line
Next Line
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]